# how to make a pop up window advertisement

Tags: javascript, html, popup

wondering how to pop up window advertisements works and how to make them. So while visitors will visit a website it will automatically open a page in a new pop windows for the first click.. I am really keen to learn this. Thanks

Comment: You might be better with a popover as popup windows are so 1990s unless you really want to ruin user experience. Is this for a porn site?

Comment: so how http://www.popads.net/ ads are works, pop up blockers can't block their ads... how to make something like this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
window.open('http://www.yourdomain.com/yourad.html','popupad','width=200,height=150')
</script>
```

or

For Internet Explorer

I mage pop up

```
<script>

var newPopup=window.open("","PopupWindow","height=250,width=250");
var popContent='<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>GetSmart</TITLE></HEAD><BODY MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 LEFTMARGIN=0 TOPMARGIN=0 BOTTOMMARGIN=0>';
popContent+= '<a target="_blank" href="http://DomainURL"><img src="http://www.yourdomain.com/ads/yourimage.gif" height=250 width=250 border=0></a>';
popContent+='</BODY></HTML>';
newPopup.document.write(popContent);
newPopup.document.close();
newPopup.focus();
</script>
```

OR

Code for Netscape

```
<script>
var newPopup=window.open("","PopupWindow","height=250,width=250");
var popContent='<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>GetSmart</TITLE></HEAD><BODY MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 LEFTMARGIN=0 TOPMARGIN=0 BOTTOMMARGIN=0>';
popContent+= '<a target="_blank" href="http://DomainURL"><img src="http://www.yourdomain.com/ads/yourimage.gif" height=250 width=250 border=0></a>';
popContent+='</BODY></HTML>';
newPopup.document.write(popContent);
newPopup.document.close();
newPopup.focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new window using the `window.open(URL)` JavaScript method, but there is no guarantee that the user will allow it. That's what popup blockers are for.

**EDIT:** W3Schools have some more information on the [Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like this:

```
<body onload="window.showModalDialog('http://www.google.com');">
```

After page load, user will have option to allow or block pop-up window

Comment: Its just firefox, is a problem chrome not working... Why not try jQuery UI Popup > https://jqueryui.com/dialog/